# why on hydrolysis ATP bond releases energy?

Tags: cellular-respiration

While studying respiration all i came across was that ultimately all that cell does is for the energy currency the ATP and some useful intermediates used in the cell building but i could not figure out how contrary to the notion of supplying energy to break a bond is energy released when the phosphate bonds in ATP are broken .

Comment: There are many many chemical reactions where breaking a bond releases energy, so this notion in your question is not correct; note that releasing energy isn't the same thing as having no activation energy, you still need to put a little in but you get a lot more out.